# Prolog DCG: Writing programming language lexer

Tags: prolog, lexical-analysis, dcg

I'm trying for the moment to keep my lexer and parser separate, based on the vague advice of the book *Prolog and Natural Language Analysis*, which really doesn't go into any detail about lexing/tokenizing. So I am giving it a shot and seeing several little issues that indicate to me that there is something obvious I'm missing.

All my little token parsers seem to be working alright; at the moment this is a snippet of my code:

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

operator('(')  --> "(".      operator(')')  --> ")".
operator('[')  --> "[".      operator(']')  --> "]".
% ... etc.

keyword(array)    --> "array".
keyword(break)    --> "break".
% ... etc.
```

It's a bit repetitive but it seems to work. Then I have some stuff I don't completely love and would welcome suggestions on, but does seem to work:

```
id(id(Id)) -->
    [C],
    {
        char_type(C, alpha)
    },
    idRest(Rest),
    {
        atom_chars(Id, [C|Rest])
    }.
idRest([C|Rest]) -->
    [C],
    {
        char_type(C, alpha) ; char_type(C, digit) ; C = '_'
    },
    idRest(Rest).
idRest([]) --> [].

int(int(Int)) --> integer(Int).

string(str(String)) -->
    "\"",
    stringContent(Codes),
    "\"",
    {
        string_chars(String, Codes)
    }.
stringContent([C|Chars]) -->
    stringChar(C), stringContent(Chars).
stringContent([]) --> [].

stringChar(0'\n) --> "\\n".
stringChar(0'\t) --> "\\t".
stringChar(0'\") --> "\\\"".
stringChar(0'\") --> "\\\\".
stringChar(C) --> [C].
```

The main rule for my tokenizer is this:

```
token(X) --> whites, (keyword(X) ; operator(X) ; id(X) ; int(X) ; string(X)).
```

It's not perfect; I will see `int` get parsed into `in,id(t)` because `keyword(X)` comes before `id(X)`. So I guess that's the first question.

The bigger question I have is that I do not see how to properly integrate comments into this situation. I have tried the following:

```
skipAhead --> [].
skipAhead --> (comment ; whites), skipAhead.

comment --> "/*", anything, "*/".
anything --> [].
anything --> [_], anything.

token(X) --> skipAhead, (keyword(X) ; operator(X) ; id(X) ; int(X) ; string(X)).
```

This does not seem to work; the parses that return (and I get many parses) do not seem to have the comment removed. I'm nervous that my comment rule is needlessly inefficient and probably induces a lot of unnecessary backtracking. I'm also nervous that `whites//0` from dcg/basics is deterministic; however, that part of the equation seems to work, it's just integrating it with the comment skipping that doesn't seem to.

As a final note, I don't see how to handle propagating parse errors back to the user with line/column information from here. It feels like I'd have to track and thread through some kind of current line/column info and write it into the tokens and then maybe try to rebuild the line if I wanted to do something similar to how llvm does it. Is that fair or is there a "recommended practice" there?

The whole code can be found [in this haste](http://hastebin.com/daminicofe).

Comment: Good reason for nervousness wrt. `comment//0`: `phrase(comment,"/**/*/")` is true, but should rather fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this code to support error reporting, that itself must be handled with care, sprinkling meaningful messages and 'skip rules' around the code. But there is not ready-to-use alternative: a DCG is a nice computation engine, but it cannot compete out-of-the-box with specialized parsing engines, that are able to emit error messages automatically, exploiting the theoretical properties of the targeted grammars...

```
:- dynamic text_length/1.

parse_conf_cs(Cs, AST)   :-
    length(Cs, TL),
    retractall(text_length(_)),
    assert(text_length(TL)),
    phrase(cfg(AST), Cs).
....
%%  tag(?T, -X, -Y)// is det.
%
%   Start/Stop tokens for XML like entries.
%   Maybe this should restrict somewhat the allowed text.
%
tag(T, X, Y) -->
    pos(X), unquoted(T), pos(Y).
....

%%  pos(-C, +P, -P) is det.
%
%   capture offset from end of stream
%
pos(C, P, P) :- text_length(L), length(P, Q), C is L - Q.
```

tag//3 is just an example usage, in this parser I'm building an editable AST, so I store the positions to be able to properly attribute each nested part in an editor...

*edit*

a small enhancement for id//1: SWI-Prolog has specialized code_type/2 for that:

```
1 ?- code_type(0'a, csymf).
true.

2 ?- code_type(0'1, csymf).
false.
```

so (glossing over literal transformation)

```
id([C|Cs]) --> [C], {code_type(C, csymf)}, id_rest(Cs).

id_rest([C|Cs]) --> [C], {code_type(C, csym)}, id_rest(Cs).
id_rest([]) --> [].
```

depending on your attitude to generalize small snippets, and the actual grammar details, id_rest//1 could be written in reusable fashion, and made deterministic

```
id([C|Cs]) --> [C], {code_type(C, csymf)}, codes(csym, Cs).

% greedy and deterministic
codes(Kind, [C|Cs]) --> [C], {code_type(C, Kind)}, !, codes(Kind, Cs).
codes(Kind, []), [C] --> [C], {\+code_type(C, Kind)}, !.
codes(_, []) --> [].
```

this stricter definition of id//1 would also allow to remove some ambiguity wrt identifiers with keyword prefix: recoding keyword//1 like

```
keyword(K) --> id(id(K)), {memberchk(K, [
    array,
    break,
...
]}.
```

will correctly identify

```
?- phrase(tokenize(Ts), `if1*2`).
Ts = [id(if1), *, int(2)] ;
```

Your string//1 (OT: what unfortunate clash with library(dcg/basics):string//1) is an easy candidate for implementing a simple 'error recovery strategy':

```
stringChar(0'\") --> "\\\\".
stringChar(0'") --> pos(X), "\n", {format('unclosed string at ~d~n', [X])}.
```

It's an example of 'report error *and* insert missing token', so the parsing can go on...

Answer (score 5):

It currently still looks a bit strange  (`unreadableNamesLikeInJavaAnyone?`), but in its core it is quite solid, so I have only a few comments about some aspects of the code and the questions:

1. Separating lexing from parsing makes perfect sense. It is also a perfectly acceptable solution to store line and column information along with each token, leaving tokens (for example) of the form `l_c_t(Line,Column,Token)` or `Token-lc(Line,Column)` for the parser to process.
2. Comments are always nasty, or should I say, often not-nesty? A useful pattern in DCGs is often to go for the longest match, which you are already using in some cases, but not yet for `anything//0`. So, reordering the two rules may help you to skip everything that is meant to be commented away.
3. Regarding the determinism: It is OK to commit to the first parse that matches, but do it only once, and resist the temptation to mess up the declarative grammar.
4. In DCGs, it is elegant to use `|` instead of `;`.
5. `tokenize//1`? Come on! That's just `tokens//1`. It makes sense in all directions.

Comment: I have never been able to come to a conclusive decision about whether camelcase is OK or not in Prolog... if they are widely considered unpopular I will return to underscores. I really like the idea of Token-loc(Line,Col) though, easy to ignore unless necessary.

Comment: `itIsEasyToSeeThatIdentifiersInCamelCaseCannotBeEasilyRead`, whereas using `names_with_underscores_are_perfectly_readable_even_for_longer_names`.

Comment: I have too many years of Java experience to agree that it is "easy to see." We are trained by what we use daily.

Comment: `okIfItIsAsNiceToYouAsTheOtherWayGoUseItButTheBuiltInsWillLookOutOfStyleThen`!

Comment: s(X), also for the camelcaseexamples. me eyes just popped open. it's all about the contrast between different characters: and that contrast happens to be higher between `_` and `[0-9a-zA-Z] than between `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]`. One question remains: Say, I got a binary predicate and I would like to choose a name like `firstArgumentDescription_secondArgumentDescription`, how would I split the phrases such that they are still discernible (separated by `_`)? With a double underscore, perhaps, like this? `first_argument_description__second_argument_description/2`.

Comment: I would still use only a single underscore, like in `call_residue_vars/2`, which only has two arguments and uses `residue_vars` to denote the second argument.